# Did I forget to partition my HD? Is this even possible?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I installed a new HD to replace a smaller drive that was starting to fail. Fortunately the old drive was still mostly working so I was able to copy everything to the new drive, except for the few files that had errors. I verified the new drive had everything and disconnected the old drive. I use mergerfs and got that going again too. The virtual drive also saw everything. But when I open plex and start browsing the libraries, many of the files are missing. When I look in a shell either in the actual drive or the virtual drive, the files are there. I thought perhaps it was a permissions issue, but they all have the same permissions. But then I noticed something. It seems that the new drive doesn't have a partition??? See /dev/sdd below:

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-id

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_500GB_S3Z1NB0K407322F -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_500GB_S3Z1NB0K407322F-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST3000VN000-1HJ166_W6A0WT1E -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST3000VN000-1HJ166_W6A0WT1E-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST6000DM003-2CY186_WF302ZH2 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST6000DM003-2CY186_WF302ZH2-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZCT0Z3NC -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZCT0Z3NC-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZCT126M7 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c5008ba1a16a -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c5008ba1a16a-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c500ad0e827b -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c500ad0e827b-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c500b60bbee0 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c500b60bbee0-part1 -> ../../sde1
*** lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5000c500b68f6daa -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5002538e403174b6 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 10 11:45 wwn-0x5002538e403174b6-part1 -> ../../sda1
```

WTH??? Is that even possible? How could I copy files to it if it didn't have a partition? Is this likely the cause for plex to not be able to see the files on that drive, even though the filesystem sees them? Is there an easy way to fix it without having to copy everything to the disk again? Fortunately I still have the failing disk so I could do that if necessary.

Here's some of the output from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B51746F5-BC86-48AB-A769-5EFBCD2F0527

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdc1 2048 5860532223 5860530176 2.7T Linux filesystem

// this one
Disk /dev/sdd: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E4402E59-8CB0-454E-A7B3-935AD70C4CB7

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sde1 2048 15628052479 15628050432 7.3T Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** This is not good indeed: *How did you copy the old to the new disk?* `ddrescue`? `dd`?? if yes: very unlikely that it didn't copy the partition table...

Comment: I just used cp -R. The files are definitely on the new disk though. So weird! I'm going to reformat AND PARTITION it tonight.

Comment: Use `ddrescue` instead of repartition and reformat.  So yes, it's possible to do it with `cp --recursive`:  Linux allows you to do powerful things but does not protect you from doing dumb things...  **:-D ;-)**